# How to find location of already downloaded datasets with Scikit Learn on Linux?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, iris-dataset

I use Debian Linux and I'm trying to find where my already downloaded datasets were stored.

On /home/usuario/scikit_learn_data, there insn't any file. I thougth all downloaded datasets would be stored here (on download, I didn't specified any custom location).

There's my code to download datasets:

```
import os
from sklearn import datasets

current_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_directory)

iris = datasets.load_iris()
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

datasets.get_data_home() 
print(iris)
```

AS you can see, I downloaded two datasets. But, as I said before, there's isn't any file on /home/usuario/scikit_learn_data. So, Where are the downloaded data files???

I am trying to figure out where are my downloaded datasets files. I have little memory (this is a business requirement) on the computer I am working with, so I have to manage to delete these files. But I just can not find them!

Answer (score 1):

I think some datasets like iris are installed along with the sklearn package.
I was able to find them in the following location:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/data/
```